# Rails, strict associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I have created my model:

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :player
 has_one :basis
 has_one :carcass
 has_one :weapon
end
```

How I can make this model able to save itself ONLY when it got its player, basis, carcass, weapon? What I need to ad to my validation?

Comment: Use [validates_presence_of](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods/validates_presence_of) validation helper.

Comment: Something like `validates_presence_of :player` ?

Comment: Yes. Look at other validation helpers. May be they will useful for you too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can validate the state of objects before they go into the database using [Active Record's validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) feature.

In your Vehicle model, define your validations as follows:

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
  has_one :carcass
  has_one :weapon

  validates :player,  presence: true
  validates :carcass, presence: true
  validates :weapon,  presence: true
end
```

This should prevent your `Vehicle` to be saved if any of your references is missing.

Good luck!

**Edit**

You can shorten the validation rules:

```
validates :player, :carcass, :weapon, presence: true
```